# PHP Parse IcoMoon JSON

Tags: php, json

IcoMoon creates font icons using css classes. It also generates a JSON file. I'm working on a php a project where it would be helpful to loop through their JSON font file and get all the font names.

```
{
    "IcoMoonType": "selection",
    "icons": [
        {
            "icon": {
                "paths": [
                    "1230912-3", "1230912-3", "1230912-3"
                ],
                "grid": 0,
                "tags": [
                    "home-addusers"
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "order": 23,
                "id": 56,
                "prevSize": 32,
                "code": 58880,
                "name": "home-addusers",
                "ligatures": ""
            },
            "setIdx": 0,
            "iconIdx": 0
        },
```

The name is under properties. I'd like to loop through all the icons and use the font names. Here's what I have so far.

```
$icons_data = '/selection.json');
$icons = json_decode($icons_data,true);

foreach($icons['icons'] as $key=>$val){
    echo $val['name'];
}
```

Comment: So, just use `$val['properties']['name']`?

Comment: That does it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mind accepting it as an answer? Just posted it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't drilling down quite far enough; you need to use `$val['properties']['name']`.